# C++ multiple threads and processes in vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads, stdvector

While going through a c++ tutorial book(it's in Spanish so I apologize if my translation to English is not as proper as it should be) I have come across a particular code snippet that I do not fully understand in terms of the different processes that are happening in the background. For example, in terms of multiple address spaces, how would I determine if these are all withing the context of a single process(being that multiple threads are being added over each push to the vector)? How would I determine if each thread is different from the other if they have the exact same computation being made?)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int addthreads = 0;

void squarenum(int x) {

   addthreads += x * x * x;

}

int main() {

        vector<thread> septhread;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){

          septhread.push_back(thread(&squarenum, i));

        }

        for (auto& th : septhread){

          th.join();

        }

        cout << "Your answer = " << addthreads << endl;

        system("pause");

        return 0;

}
```

Every answer defaults to 2025, that much I understand. My basic issue is understanding the first part of my question.

By the way, the compiler required(if you are on Linux):

g++ -std=gnu++ -pthread threadExample.cpp -o threadExample

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you're asking. This code creates threads. Threads, by definition, share an address space. (The code, by the way, is broken. The results of all these threads trying to access and modify `addthreads` at the same time is undefined. But the `vector` is only accessed by one thread.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I apologize if my questions seems a little weird. Basically, the book made it seem as if there were multiple address spaces being accessed at different places as there are multiple threads being pushed to `septhread` , by your answer(thank you by the way) I guess that there are no multiple address spaces being used and that the threads are not different from each other, correct?

Comment: This is correct. Threads, by definition, share a common address space. It is processes that have individual, isolated, address spaces.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I concur, the book is garbage but sadly is what I have.There are some great tutorials online that I have been using as well so that is great. As for the undefined behavior part, should I not be getting the answer I am getting then? I would agree that the code itself is a bad example, but it's working on my machine and it made sense to me. I am a beginner with no teacher or formal training, but if you guys could explain these concepts to me I would take your advice to heart.

Comment: "Undefined behavior" means you may get the expected answer, or you may get a random answer, and you may get a different answer every time you execute the program.

Comment: Why do you expect 2025? Don't you expect that, for example, one thread might read a value, then another thread might read the same value, then each thread might add to the value it read, and then each thread will write back the value it got, one write clobbering the other?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you are right, I am somewhat failing to see that. I am missing a lot of theoretical knowledge and practical experience in that regard! But I will continue to dissect this to better understand the process as to see how it is an example of undefined behavior(which I think I am starting to get)

Comment: If you want to observe that `squarenum` is being executed on different threads, you can inspect [`std::this_thread::get_id()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id) (values will differ).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik   Basically, correct thread programming, especially with multiple cores and not just a single core, is hard. The memory model and different cache levels comes into play. There's several good videos on cppcon https://www.youtube.com/user/CppCon which may help as well.  One of the critical things to remember about threads is that a very large fraction of the time things will work but that is misleading. Often errors show up under different loads but may not show up for long periods of time. They just lurk ready to create havoc when least expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `thread` is a "thread of execution" within a process, sharing the same address space, resources, etc. Depending on the operating system, hardware, etc, they may or may not run on the same CPU or CPU Thread.

A major issue with thread programming, as a result, is managing access to resources. If two threads access the same resource at the same time, Undefined Behavior can occur. If they are both reading, it may be fine, but if one is writing at the same moment the other is reading, numerous outcomes ensue. The simplest is that both threads are running on separate CPUs or cores and so the reader does not see the change made by the writer due to cache. Another is that the reader sees only a portion of the write (if it's a 64-bit value they might only see 32-bits changed).

Your code performs a read-modify-store operation, so the first thread to come along sees the value '0', calculates the result of `x*x*x`, adds it to `0` and stores the result.

Meanwhile the next thread comes along and does the same thing, it also sees `0` before performing its calculation, so it writes `0 + x*x*x` to the value, overwriting the first thread.

These threads might *not* be in the order that you launched them; it's possible for thread #30 to get the first execution cycle rather than thread #1.

You may need to consider looking at `std::atomic` or `std::mutex`.

Comment: ah that makes sense. Thank you @kfsone, that makes more sense now. Cheers!